# "Optimizing" access to cursors in Android: Position vs Column names

Tags: android, android-cursor

From the performance point of view: Is it fine if in every access to my cursors I use something like :

```
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "my_column_name";
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
```

Or I should see a **measurable** improvement in performance if I use this instead:

```
public static final int COLUMN_POSITION = #column_position;
cursor.getString(COLUMN_POSITION);
```

I prefer the first approach since the rest of the code is not depending on the position of the columns in the query, but only on the name of the column.

Is worth sacrificing this for the "performance improvement" of accessing the cursor using constant positions instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess this has nothing to do with android. in SQLite, accessing column through index (column position) is supposed to be faster.

Comment: I know that, my question is: "significantly" faster ?

Comment: i don't know the exact number, but i think the difference will be significant only if u have 100k+ columns in a table. The best way to determine this is to create a sample project and calculate the time difference using `System.nanoTime()`

Comment: This does pertain to Android. A Cursor returned through a ContentProvider has no requirement that it be backed by SQLite. In fact, a great many aren't. You can look at the implementations of the cursors to find out for yourself. In a quick look of AbstractCursor.getColumnIndex, you'll absolutely want to cache the index values yourself if you have more than just a couple of columns ( the look up is O(n) where n is the number of columns).

Answer (score 29):

To answer your question (and mine by the way), i've made a few tests.

This test was basically to check how much time the query took for those two cases:

1. Using the `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME))` method
2. Getting the column id first and then calling directly the `cursor.getString(COLUMN_POSITION)` method

To make the performance test significative i've inserted **5000** lines in a database and then i've made a query threw my `ContentProvider` on those elements.

Results:

```
 ___________________________________________________________________________
| Column count| Time (ms) getColumnIndex | Time (ms) columnId | improvement |
|_____________|__________________________|____________________|_____________|
| 500         | 34564                    | 30401              | 13%         |
| 200         |  9987                    |  8502              | 17%         |
| 100         |  4713                    |  4004              | 17%         |
| 50          |  2400                    |  1971              | 21%         |
| 20          |  1088                    |   915              | 19%         |
|___________________________________________________________________________|
```

So, getting the column id first and the call directly the `getString()`method will take around **20%** less time.

---

## Test method details :

Platform : *Nexus 7 (2012) on Android 4.3*

Database creation :

```
public static int TESTSPEEDCOLUMNCOUNT = 200;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("CREATE TABLE " + Tables.TESTSPEED + " (");
sb.append(BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ");
for (int i = 0; i < (TESTSPEEDCOLUMNCOUNT - 1); ++i) {
    sb.append("C" + i + " TEXT, ");
}
sb.append("C" + (TESTSPEEDCOLUMNCOUNT - 1) + " TEXT)");
db.execSQL(sb.toString());
```

TestCase:

```
public class ProviderTestSpeed extends ProviderTestCase2<MyProvider> {

    private ContentValues createElementForId(String id) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 0; i < TESTSPEEDCOLUMNCOUNT; ++i) {
            cv.put("C" + i, id);
        }
        return cv;
    }



    public void testSpeed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "testSpeed start columnCount = " + columnCount);
        ArrayList<ContentValues> list = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
        ContentValues[] tabcv = {};
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            list.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
                ContentValues cv = createElementForId(String.valueOf(i));
                list.add(cv);
            }
            mContentResolver.bulkInsert(TestSpeedCONTENT_URI, list.toArray(tabcv));
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "testSpeed insertFinished");
        Cursor cursor = mContentResolver.query(TestSpeedCONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.d(TAG, "testSpeed itemCount = " + cursor.getCount() + " columnCount=" + cursor.getColumnCount());

        // build the tab to avoid dynamic allocation during the mesure
        ArrayList<String> listColumns = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < TESTSPEEDCOLUMNCOUNT; ++i) {
            listColumns.add("C" + i);
        }
        String[] tabColumnsType = {};
        String[] tabColumns = listColumns.toArray(tabColumnsType);

        Date now = new Date();
        long start = now.getTime();
        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < TESTSPEEDCOLUMNCOUNT; ++i) {
                // get the all the columns of the table
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tabColumns[i]));
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        now = new Date();
        long end = now.getTime();

        Log.d(TAG, "testSpeed took " + (end - start) + " with getColumnIndex at each time");
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        now = new Date();
        start = now.getTime();
        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < TESTSPEEDCOLUMNCOUNT; ++i) {
                // get the all the columns of the table using directly the column id
                cursor.getString(i);
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        now = new Date();
        end = now.getTime();
        Log.d(TAG, "testSpeed took " + (end - start) + " with getColumnIndex before loop");
    }
}
```

I think that the performance drop between 200 to 500 come from the cursor window. I had a lot of logs like that above 200 columns:

```
W/CursorWindow(1628): Window is full: requested allocation 2412 bytes, free space 988 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
```

Comment: In either case, you're calling getString(index). The bigger take away here is that getColumnIndex on 500 columns takes _nearly 4 seconds_ on it's own. Given what the getColumnIndex code looks like, it's easy and worthwhile to cache it.

Comment: This answer is now a little outdated.  If you look at the source code for `getColumnIndex(String columnName)` in `SQLiteCursor.java` you can see that they create a map of String (name) to Integer (index) at the top of the method.  Therefore the column name lookup now only happens once per column, per table.